# Application javascript file cannot be found in Rails 5 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

I am having some issues loading jQuery in my Rails 5 app and I noticed that in my `application.html.erb` where I have the line:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

It renders in production as:

```
<script src="/assets/application-6ae626540db9f70a95910bd840e1005a357fae74302f0d8866bd4da5fd67d6cc.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
```

with a 404 error, not found.  I recently moved to Rails 5 but I am used to seeing all the assets listed there.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you build the assets as part of your deploy process? Please take a look here: https://launchschool.com/blog/rails-asset-pipeline-best-practices

Comment: I thought that automatically fires during deployment?